# Display chat Messages Using Qt(C++)

Tags: c++, qt

i spent days searching how to fix a problem i tried different approach but with no result. my problem is this : i have developed a chat program with Qt Framework (C++) and i want to display chat history. in each arrived message there is an icon of the user his name and the exact date when the message arrived.and ofcourse the message. the message can contain text as will as icons (.gif or just .png)(just like facebook or skype)
i want like that exactly:
[Like This Exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWMOQ.png)

this what i have tried. 
i created a class named MessageText derived from QPlaintextEdit which has a method called append to add new Messages but the problem i can't add icons and the user can't change the message color.
this is my code:

```
 #include "MessageText.h"
    #include <QTextEdit>
    MessageText::MessageText()
    {   
        this->setObjectName("asf");
        this->setStyleSheet("#asf{background-color:#AACC44;}");
        this->setReadOnly(true);    
    }

    void MessageText::appendMessage( QString icon, QString name, QString text)
    {
        QLabel *nameTime1=new QLabel(this);  //container of user's name and the             date
        QLabel *iconContiner1=new QLabel(this); /container of user's icon
        nameTime1->setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(242,242,242);");
        nameTime1->setText("           "+QString(QChar(0x200E))+name);
        iconContiner1->setStyleSheet("background-image:url(ua/"+icon+".png);background-repeat:no-repeat;");

            this->appendPlainText(+"\n\n"+text); // Adds the message to the widget

           nameTime1->setGeometry(0,(this->document()->size().height()-2)*22,1056,18); //to put new message just after the previous
           iconContiner1->setGeometry(2,(this->document()->size().height()-2)*22,27,27);
            this->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(this->verticalScrollBar()->maximum());
            nameTime1->show();
           iconContiner1->show();
    }
```

what is the best approach to achieve thisi will be so thankful
thank you soo much in advance.

Comment: Why did you derive a class from QPlaintextEdit ?

Comment: because i defined a method in this class(append) to append each time new messages also to write only short code. becose there is a public conversation as will as private converstation.

Comment: i'm sure this not the best way to do it. if you can lead me to a better way i will be so thankful

Comment: You can do same thing with QTextEdit or QTextBrowser

Comment: Yes you are right. i have already used QTextEdit  but same Problems

Comment: You should add the name and icon as part of the document, not as widgets on top of the view, otherwise you will have to manually move/hide/show these "overlay" widgets whenever the text moves.
Or do you have a new `MessageText` instance for each incoming message?

Comment: i don't know how to add the bame and icon as part of the document ? can you please show me how!

Comment: i don't know how to add the name and icon as part of the document ? can you please show me howto do that!. i have already tried   to manually move/hide/show whenever the text moves and i face many problems because the user can change the text  style(italic,color,big icons small icons...) it soo hard to handle it manually . Non i have the same MessageText for all incoming messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML in QLabel's text . Like `text = "hello <img src=":/Desktop/GameAssetDesign/springgameAssets/MassBody_G.png" width = 30 height = 30>"`

[image: example]

Comment: this not exactly what i want i hope someone can help me